# Websocket Request & Response Followup, Timeout & Error Handling

Tags: javascript, websocket

When I send a message through websocket, is there anyway that I can follow up the response? I know that I can send messages in one tunnel and listen to the responses in another tunnel but what I didnt understand is how I will get them all in a meaningful order. Here is an example case:

When I click on a button on my webpage (join room) I send a JOIN_ROOM_REQUEST to the websocket on the server. And meanwhile I disable the button because I do not want the user to click again and be prompted when his join request is accepted and executed. If everything goes well, the server will send an event over the websocket so that I can now let the user to join the room. However what if the server does not respond at all? How will I handle this situation? The button hanged disabled and the state cannot be updated back to its initial state.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell if a message reached the server with WebSocket. You would have to add an `ack` style response to your own protocol and then reconnect and retry the request continuously when the ack doesn't arrive within an appropriate time limit (say a few seconds).